# JQuery Date.parse function implementation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using the daterangepicker component of jquery. The Date.parse() function of jquery gives some weird output when i pass the date as "Jan 2011". Here's the sample output for different use cases:

Code snippet:

```
var dateStr = "Jan 2011";
var dt = Date.parse(dateStr);
alert(dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getMonth());
```

Output :

```
dateStr = "Jan 2011"  : output = 25/0 (todays date is 25 feb 2011)
dateStr = "Feb 2011"  : output = 1/1
dateStr = "Dec 2011"  : output = 1/11
```

So for any other month that Jan, the date is set to 1st date of the month, whereas only for jan the date is set to the current date.

Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: you might give the http://www.datejs.com/ parser a try.

Comment: may be because Jan has already passed? try setting your machine clock to jan and then see what is the output

Comment: Setting machine clock to jan or a date before jan works for jan 2011, but when u call Date.parse("Jan 2010") it fails again. For a past month, it should still give the output as "01-MM-yyyy" ..  and the same fails only for Jan. Works fine for rest of the months.

Answer (score 0):

It's not standart `Date.parse` function in you example.
Standart `parse` function returns **numeric** result, not **Date** object.
[Javascript parse() Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

In you example `parse` function returns **Date** object.
function `Date.parse` was redefined in you code. Please check it.

Standart `parse` function always returns first day in month in your case

Comment: Please consider replacing that w3schools reference with a decent one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var d = Date.parse("Jan 2011");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display milliseconds between a specified date and Jan 2011.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

The parse() method parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds between the date string and midnight of Jan 20111